# Geocoder google maps longitude and latitude lookup

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, geolocation

I have a longitude and latitude lookup working great with an ajax call like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "<?php echo addslashes($_POST['street'].' '.$_POST['house_number'].', '.$_POST['postal_code'].', '.$_POST['city'].', '.$_POST['country']); ?>";

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        var request_key = '<?php echo $ajax_request_key; ?>';
        var url = '<?php echo $settings['base_url'].'/site/templates/ajax/add_vacancy_latitude_and_longitude.php?vacancy_id='.$_POST['vacancy_id']; ?>';

        //add longitude and latitude to database
        $.post(url, { this_latitude:latitude, this_longitude:longitude, this_request_key:request_key }, function(data) {  });

    }

}); 
</script>
```

But this only works with an ajax call. Is there a way I can do it with an http request so I can immediately query my mysql database for vacancies close by without having to do a second page load (ex. I have a search form where the user enters their postal code, I want to immediately on submit compare the longitude and latitude of their postal code with the database.

The way I can think of now is preventing the submit with jquery and making the ajax call, storing the longitude and latitude for the search into the database, then submitting the form and querying the database with the stored longitude and latitude. Somehow I think there must be a more efficient way.

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: You can try use curl in php, You will have all info before page load   http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Scott there is an efficient way using curl.

You can directly make a http call like this

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false

you have to pass 2 parameters to the url
1. address
2. sensor

Enjoy!

- Datta

Comment: thanks! perfect; in combination with php curl as mentioned in YamahaSY's comment